# Tensorial $q$-forms of type $\rho$ on $P$ are isomorphic to $\Lambda^q(M;P\times_\rho V)$

Tags: tensors, differential-forms, principal-bundles

While reading the appendix of Friedrich's "Dirac Operators in Riemannian Geometry" I met the following definition.

Let $P$ be a $G$-principal bundle over $M$, and $\rho:G\to GL(V)$ a representation.

A $q$ form  $w \in \Lambda^q(P,V)$ with values in $V$, is called *tensorial of type $\rho$* if

1) $R_g^*w = \rho(g^{-1})w$   (pseudo-tensorialty, $R_g:P\to P$ is the right  action )

2) $w_p(X_1,\dots, X_q) = 0$ if at least one of the  vectors $X_i$ is vertical i.e. $d\pi(X_i) = 0$ ($\pi:P\to M$ is the projection).

Then  the author states the following very interesting proposition without proof

> The vector space of tensorial $q$-forms  of type $\rho$ on $P$ with values in $V$ is isomorphic to the vector space of $\Lambda^q(M;P\times_\rho V)$ of $q$-forms on $M$ with values in the associated vector bundle  $P\times_\rho V$.
>
> The question is how is this isomorphism defined?

It doesn't seems straightforward to me. Given $w\in\Lambda^q(M;P\times_\rho V)$, we have something that takes tangent vectors to $M$, but we want something that takes tangent vectors to $P$, So I thought of simply pulling back $w$ using $\pi$. But the form $\pi^*w $ satisfy 2) but not 1) since $R_g^*\pi^* w = (\pi\circ R_g)^* w$ and $\pi\circ R_g = \pi$ because the right action preserve the fiber. So we would have that $R_g^*\pi^* w = \pi^* w $.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to go the other direction first. Given $\omega\in \Lambda^q(P,V)$ tensorial of type $\rho$, how do we define $\phi\in \Lambda^q(M,P\times_\rho V)$? Given $x\in M$, $p\in P$ with $\pi(p)=x$, and $Y_i\in T_xM$, we want to choose $X_i\in T_pP$ with $\pi_*X_i = Y_i$ and compute $\omega_p(X_1,\dots,X_q)$ in order to define $\phi_x(Y_1,\dots,Y_q)$. The fact that $\omega$ is pseudo-tensorial and property (2) will say that this is exactly a well-defined element of $P\times_\rho V$.

Comment: @TedShifrin indeed, this is the easy direction, but writing out explicitly the inverse isomorphism seems a bit harder. The pullback via $\pi$ seems to be the right way to go but we need to "untangle" the pullback bundle $\pi^*P\times_\rho V$ in order to see the tensorial behaviour, I can see how to do this locally, but i'm not sure how to do it globally...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was noted in the comments, the easy direction is going from a section $\alpha$ of the bundle $\Lambda^k(T^*P)\otimes (P\times V)$ (V valued differential forms on P) that verifies the conditions i) and ii) to a section $\alpha_M$ of the bundle $\Lambda^k(T^*M)\otimes(P\times_G V)$.

Let $\pi:P \rightarrow M$ be the projection. Once a choice of connection has been made, it induces isomorphisms fibre-wise $\pi_{*p}: H_p\subset T_pP \rightarrow T_\pi(p)M$. Via these isomorphisms one can lift vectors horizontally. So, denoting $\mathscr{p}$ the canonical projection from $P\times V$ to $P\times_G V$, $\alpha_M$ can be defined by:

### $\alpha_{M,x}(X_1,\dots,X_k) = \mathscr{p}(\alpha_p(\tilde X_1,...,\tilde X_k))$

where $p$ is an arbitrary element of $\pi^{-1}(\{x\})$ and $\tilde X_i$ is obtained from $X_i$ by lifting horizontally by the procedure described above. Conditions i) and ii) guarantee that this map is well defined and independent of the choice of $p$.

The opposite direction is slightly more difficult to write down, but indeed we expect, given $\alpha_M$, to get $\alpha$ by pulling back $\alpha_M$ via $\pi$. The form $\pi^*\alpha_M$ gives is a section of $\Lambda^k(T^*P)\otimes \pi^*(P\times_G V)$, but it is not immediately clear if the vector bundle $\pi^*(P\times_G V)$ can naturally be identified with a known fibre bundle over P, namely, $P\times V$. We need to show that this is the case.

Recall that:

### $\pi^*(P\times_G V) = \{ (p,\mathcal{V}) \in P \times( P\times_G V), \tilde{\pi}(\mathcal{V})=\pi(p)\}$

Where $\tilde\pi : P\times_G V \rightarrow M$ is the projection of the vector bundle $P\times_G V$.

We need to show that this bundle is trivial. This can be achieved in the following manner: Let $r\in P$; define a linear map $\tilde\rho(r)$ from $V$ into $\tilde\pi^{-1}(\{\pi(r)\})$ by $v \mapsto \mathscr{p}((r,v))$.

Note that $\tilde\rho(rg)=\tilde\rho(r)\rho(g)$ since $\mathscr{p}((rg,v))=\mathscr{p}((r,\rho(g)v))$. So we can define a map from $\pi^*(P\times_G V)$ to $P\times V$ by $(p,\mathcal{V})\mapsto (p,\tilde{\rho}(p)^{-1}\mathcal{V})$. Once we've proven that the association $r\mapsto \tilde\rho(r)$ is smooth, we've shown what we wanted.

Via this global trivialisation of $\pi^*P\times_G V$ we see that we do indeed get, via pull-back, a tensorial $V$ valued differential form. I hope this helps you !

Comment: I will read this in the next days, for now  thank you!

Comment: "The form $\pi^*\alpha_M$ gives is a section of $\Lambda^k(T^*M)\otimes \pi^*(P\times_G V)$" why not $\Lambda^k(P,V)$? Also I am not sure that your map satisfies the pseudo tensoriality condition. Nevertheless. thanks to your suggestions I manage to prove that a bijection is given by the map that associates to $\alpha_M\mapsto\varphi $ $\varphi_{(g,v)}(X_1,\dots,X_n) = g^{-1}\cdot \alpha_{M (\pi(g,v))}(d\pi X_1,\dots, d\pi X_n)$ or in other words $\varphi = \mu_{g^{-1}}\cdot \pi^* \alpha_M$ where $\mu$ is the multiplication map and $g\in G$ is element of the group in the correct fiber.

Comment: The inverse of this map is given by $\alpha_M(X_1,\dots, X_n) = \mu_g\cdot\varphi(\tilde{X}_1,\dots, \tilde{X}_n)$.

Comment: The pullback of a form defines a priori a form on the so called pullback bundle.. In most cases it is obvious how to identify the pullback bundle with a known bundle but in this case it is not that clear. You need the extra step to go from $\pi^*P\times_G V$ to $P\times V$. In the second from last paragraph, I describe that you have to compose pullback with a further map, namely, what I call $\tilde{\rho}^{-1}$. When you do that you see that it is tensorial because $\tilde{\rho}(pg)=\tilde{\rho}(p)\rho(g)$.

Comment: In my notations: $\Lambda^k(P,V)=\Lambda^k(T^*P)\otimes(P\times V)$ and there was also a mistake in the sentenced you copied, now corrected, it should read $\Lambda^k(T^*P)\otimes \pi^*(P\times_G V)$

Comment: I see... Thanks for the answer, now it is clear. Just for the records, there is a good explanation  in the Kobayashi Nomizu volume 1, just after the definition of tensorial q-form.